# How to make bootstrap grid system elements, masonry style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to use bootstrap in this way:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    Content..
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    Content..
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    Content..
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    Content..
</div>
//And so on..
```

These div's are being added dynamically.

I don't know if there's an extra class I could add to the div's to make them masonry style, but for a visual example, Here's what I'm getting so far:

[image: bootstrap grid system non masonry style]

and Here's what I'm looking to achieve:

[image: bootstrap grid system masonry style]

Does anyone know any classes I can add to achieve this effect?

Comment: here you have masonry jquery solution http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/mywEMR and here pure css https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might help you :  http://www.bootply.com/118335
Also try this

```
<div class="two-columns">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="double-wide">
</div>
<div class="two-columns">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Also,
https://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/